# Turbolinks and jQuery compatibility on Rails 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a hidden field that's activated when clicked on the link using jQuery. When clicking on the link, the field appears just for a second and then disappears.

```
  $('.use-different-card').on "click", ->
    $(".card-on-file").hide()
    $(".card-fields").removeClass("hidden")
```

When I remove turbolinks,  jQuery seems to work just fine.

I've tryied adding [compatibility.coffee](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/blob/master/src/turbolinks/compatibility.coffee) but I had no luck.

This is my source tree.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require turbolinks
//= require compatibility
//= require_tree .
```

**Anything suggestion on what to try next?**

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that your jquery isn't reloaded on page "change".  Instead of wrapping your functions in a document.ready(), use the following:

```
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('.use-different-card').on "click", ->
  $(".card-on-file").hide()
  $(".card-fields").removeClass("hidden")
})
```

**Update**:  Also, your jquery.turbolinks is being required after Jquery.ujs!  Change your requirements order.  As per the gem docs for jquery.turbolinks you need your application.css file to be like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks  /*Notice this must be before jquery_ujs */
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Once you have this order corrected, you may not need to use the `turbolinks:load` call anymore.

Comment: I've tried adding the following, but no luck. Any suggestions?

$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $('.use-different-card').on "click", ->
    $(".card-on-file").hide()
    $(".card-fields").removeClass("hidden")

Comment: @LauroSilva which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: See the update to the answer.  Should fix your issue.